# what have I done to my TextViews?

Tags: android

OK, so I have a cursor  adapter that I cobbled together from various source and mostly seems to work -except my name fields.  I have two checkboxes on a listview for each name but my names are all coming out the same (the first name)

Anyone spot the problem I've create?  Your help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Cursor c;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemCheckedHere = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemCheckedLate = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<Integer> itemCheckedIdx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int idxCol;
int idx;

// itemChecked will store the position of the checked items.

public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        itemCheckedHere.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
        itemCheckedLate.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }
}

public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView studentName;
    ImageView studentPhoto;

    if (inView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_attendance, null);
    }

    final CheckBox cBoxH = (CheckBox) inView.findViewById(R.id.attend);
    final CheckBox cBoxL = (CheckBox) inView.findViewById(R.id.late);

    // set up name field

    studentName = (TextView) inView.findViewById(R.id.stuname);   
    if (studentName != null)
    {
            int index = c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_NAME);
            String name = c.getString(index);
            studentName.setText(name);
    } 




    cBoxH.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.attend);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true);
                // do some operations here
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
                // do some operations here
            }
        }
    });
    cBoxL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.late);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
               itemCheckedLate.set(pos, true);
               // do some operations here
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
               itemCheckedLate.set(pos, false);
               // do some operations here
            }
        }
    });
    cBoxH.setChecked(itemCheckedHere.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
    cBoxL.setChecked(itemCheckedLate.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
    // CheckBox in ListView
    // according to their original
    // position and CheckBox never
    // loss his State when you
    // Scroll the List Items.
    return inView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself. You just forgot to move the cursor to the position corresponding to the index in the ListView:

```
c.moveToPosition(pos)
```

Comment: Argh!   Thanks. I was hoping it was simple, but not so simple I look like a total n00b.  Must be tired.  Thanks Phillip!

Answer (score 1):

The cursor in the adapter is not set to the correct row.

First of all you should  get rid of your own member variables for the cursor and the context! Then try to implement the bindView method of the CursorAdapter, it will provide the cursor already set to the current row:

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemCheckedHere = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemCheckedLate = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<Integer> itemCheckedIdx = new ArrayList<Integer>();


// itemChecked will store the position of the checked items.

public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        itemCheckedHere.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
        itemCheckedLate.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }
}

public void bindView (View inView, Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super.bindView(inView,context,cursor);

    TextView studentName;
    ImageView studentPhoto;

    //inView is never null in bindView

    final CheckBox cBoxH = (CheckBox) inView.findViewById(R.id.attend);
    final CheckBox cBoxL = (CheckBox) inView.findViewById(R.id.late);

    // set up name field

    studentName = (TextView) inView.findViewById(R.id.stuname);   
    if (studentName != null)
    {
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_NAME);
            String name = cursor.getString(index);
            studentName.setText(name);
    } 

    //your other code
}

//other methods
```

}